# Regular Expression - Want to find a match for a word but only if it does not appear after certain characters

Tags: regex

Please help me find a regular expression that will do the following.....

I have a file that could contain lines such as...

```
with replace into currency;
--if at least one client currency is not found
@id_base int,              -- base currency Id
from currency            -- need this table as it stores the fx currency
```

I need to search this file and return any lines that contain the word **currency** BUT only if there is no **--** before it. The -- represents a comment and can be excluded however as you can see from the last line above I may get a case where the word is included in the comment section and non comment section so in this case it should be classed as a match so from the above file i would expect only the following lines to return.

```
with replace into currency;
from currency            -- need this table as it stores the fx currency
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is a new UNIX Linux script but flexible over which command to use e.g. grep, awk etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match with the following regex:

```
/^(?:currency.*(*ACCEPT)|(?!--).)+(*F)$/m
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts position at start of line. *(m modifier)*
- `(?:` Non-capturing group: Matches character before **"--"**.
- `currency.*(*ACCEPT)` Captures word **"currency"** and matches the rest of the line.
- `|` *or*
- `(?!--).` Something that's not **"--"**.
- `)+` More than once.
- `(*F)` Fail the match. This will only be reached if the match isn't already accepted by `(*ACCEPT)`.
- `$` Asserts position at end of the line. *(m modifier)*

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO2yV3/4)

---

> Taking the above slightly further, if I wanted to search for two words, "currency" or "market..currency". Is it possible to do this in 1 regex?

For this new requirement, see the following regex:

```
/^(?:(?!--)(?:(happyness)|(money)|(health)|.))+(?(1)(?(2)(?(3).*(*ACCEPT))))(*F)$/m
```

Comment: I had to make an amendment to the regex as that is currently returning the pattern currency whereas i wanted only the word currency e.g. "with replace into FXcurrency;" would not return as the word is FXcurrency.  Taking the above slightly further, if I wanted to search for two words, "currency" or "market..currency".  Is it possible to do this in 1 regex?

Comment: Guess I asked for that, will remember that link for my business.

Comment: @Mark Please see the new regex. Note you have to add number of conditionals when you add more capturing groups. Only when all groups are captured will all the conditionals pass, otherwise leading to `(*F)`.

Comment: Note for future readers: `$` is not necessary in this case. As `(*F)` fails the match, everything behind it wouldn't be reached anyway. If you'd like to use `$`, consider placing it before `(*ACCEPT)`.

Comment: Good morning, just checking in to see where you left the answer. As I said before I find it to be a delightful and fiendish use of syntax, but for completion I would suggest mentioning that it will work without the `(*F)` and the `(*ACCEPT)`. I haven't studied the second one, just waking up. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl One-Liner

You can use this regex:

```
(?m)^(?:(?!--).)*?currency.*
```

**With a perl one-liner:**

```
perl -ne 'print "$&\n" if m/(?m)^(?:(?!--).)*?currency.*/m' yourfile
```

**Output:**

```
with replace into currency;
from currency            -- need this table as it stores the fx currency
```